# Pushing To Detail View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have set up a `tableView` with a search bar and a list of stock names. I've inserted some code in my `Detail View Controller` to make the cells push to it and say some stuff in a label. The problem is whenever I click on one cell it shows another cell. Is there a better or more efficient way to push to a `detail View`?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewLemon: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

let tableData = ["Apple","Google","Facebook","Amazon","Exxon Mobil"]
var filteredTableData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // 1
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // 2
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return self.tableData.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    // 3
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {

        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewLemon

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{

            let Make = tableData[indexPath.row] as String

            VC.sentData1 = Make
        }
    }
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: Most of your code is checking `self.resultSearchController.active` to decide which array to use, but `prepareForSegue` isn't. So this doesn't look right.

Comment: Do you know what I should add to prepareForSegue. @Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect your `prepareForSegue` to differentiate between `filteredTableData` and `tableData` in the same way `cellForRowAtIndexPath` does. Something along the lines of:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewLemon
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let Make = self.resultSearchController.active ? 
                filteredTableData[indexPath.row] as String  : 
                tableData[indexPath.row] as String
            VC.sentData1 = Make
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I would avoid using `segue.identifier` as it is error-prone (ie. no compile error if you get it wrong). Instead you can just use if-let on the destination VC.

Rather than:

```
    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewLemon
        ...
    }
```

Use:

```
    if let VC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewLemon {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank You so much. It finally works, I owe you one. @Michael